# Búsqueda por nombre (coincidencia de cadena dentro de otra en javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, json

Estoy realizando un programa en javascript/jquery, y tengo una opción que me falta añadir a mi programa, el problema y gracia del tema, es que hacer dicha característica perfectamente con javascript vanilla, pero no caigo en la forma de poder hacerlo con jquery. Tengo un input en el que al introducir el nombre exacto de un pokemon, me lo muestre por pantalla (búsqueda que hace en el json que contiene mi programa), sin embargo, lo que quiero conseguir, es que si por ejemplo pongo,"blas" o "Blas", me salga Blastoise, sin la necesidad que ponga obligatoriamente el nombre completo. Es decir, lo que quiero es que me saque todas las coincidencias y los pokemon que tengan como raiz dicha parte del nombre. La solución para esto usando javascript vanilla, es basicamente esta:
*(respuestaObjeto[i].name.english.toLowerCase().includes(nombre.toLowerCase()))*)

Pero ¿Como adecuo esto para jquery dentro de mi codigo?

```js
//INICIANDO
$(document).ready(function () {
    //FUNCIONALIDAD BOTON CARGAR JSON
    $("#boton-json").on("click", function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "json/pokedex.json",
            success: function (resultado) { 
                //CREACION DE LA TABLA CON ID-NOMBRE-TIPO-SELECCIÓN
                var tabla = $("<table class='table table-dark'>"
                    +
                    "<tr><th><h2>Id</h2></th>" +
                    "<th><h2>Nombre</h2></th>" +
                    "<th><h2>Tipos</h2></th>" +
                    "<th><h2>Opciones</h2></th></tr>");
                //MOSTRAR TODOS LOS POKEMONS
                $.each(resultado, function (i, objetoJSON) {
                    //MOSTRAR SOLO EL POKEMON SI EL CAMPO ID Y POKEMON ESTA RELLENOS
                    if (($("#identificador").val() <= objetoJSON.id) && ($("#pokemon").val() == objetoJSON.name.english)) {
                        if ($("#pokemon").val() == objetoJSON.name.english) {
                            tabla.append(`<tr><td id='idPokemon'> ${objetoJSON.id} </td>
                         <td id='nombrePokemon'> ${objetoJSON.name.english} </td><td id='tiposPokemon'>${objetoJSON.type} 
                         </td> <td><button type='button' class='btn bg-white seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button></td></tr>`);
                        }
                    }
                    //MOSTRAR HASTA EL ID INDICADO
                    else if ((i < $("#identificador").val()) && ($("#pokemon").val() == '')) {
                        tabla.append(`<tr><td id='idPokemon'> ${objetoJSON.id} </td>
                         <td id='nombrePokemon'> ${objetoJSON.name.english} </td><td id='tiposPokemon'>${objetoJSON.type} 
                         </td> <td><button type='button' class='btn bg-white seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button></td></tr>`);
                    }
                    //MOSTRAR POKEMON SI EL ID ESTA VACIO
                    else if (($("#identificador").val() == "") && ($("#pokemon").val() == objetoJSON.name.english)) {

                        tabla.append("<tr><td id='idPokemon'>" + objetoJSON.id + "</td>" + "<td id='nombrePokemon'>" + objetoJSON.name.english + "</td>" + "<td id='tiposPokemon'>" + objetoJSON.type + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<button type='button' class='btn bg-white seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button>" + "</td></tr>");
                        //MOSTRAR TODOS LOS POKEMON
                    } else if (($("#identificador").val() === "") && ($("#pokemon").val() === "")) {

                        tabla.append("<tr><td id='idPokemon'>" + objetoJSON.id + "</td>" + "<td id='nombrePokemon'>" + objetoJSON.name.english + "</td>" + "<td id='tiposPokemon'>" + objetoJSON.type + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<button type='button' class='btn bg-white seleccionar'>Seleccionar</button>" + "</td></tr>");
                    }

                });
                //GENERAMOS EL CONTENEDOR CON LOS DATOS SEGÚN LOS CONDICIONALES RESULTANTES
                $("#contenedor").html(tabla); 

                //FUNCIONALIDAD BOTÓN SELECCIONAR
                $(".seleccionar").on('click', function () {
                    
                    //console.log("COMPROBACIÓN DE QUE EL BOTÓN MOSTRAR FUNCIONA");
                    //GUARDAMOS DATOS ID NOMBRE Y ENVIAMOS A PHP
                    $.post("php/insertar.php", { 
                        idPokemon: $(this).closest("tr").find("#idPokemon").text(),
                        nombrePokemon: $(this).closest("tr").find("#nombrePokemon").text()
                    }, function (datos) {
                        document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = datos;
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

//FUNCIONALIDAD BOTÓN MOSTRAR
$("#boton-mostrar").on('click', function () { 
    $.post("php/mostrar.php", {
    }, function (datos) {

        document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = datos;
        //FUNCIONALIDAD BOTÓN BORRAR
        $(".borrar").on('click', function () { 
            $.post("php/borrar.php", {
                idPokemon: $(this).closest("tr").find("#idPokemon").text()
            }, function (datos) {
                document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML = datos;
            });
        });
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();

    });

});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>POKEDEX - PRÁCTICA 3</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/styles.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="styles/img/icono-pagina.png" type="image/ico" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Press+Start+2P&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="portada" class="my-row ">
    <div class="container fluid padding-portada">
      <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <img src="styles/img/logopokemon.png" class="img-fluid aumento">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <script>
            window.addEventListener('load', function () {
              let myAudio = document.getElementById("myAudio");
              myAudio.onplaying = function () {
                isPlaying = true;
              };
              myAudio.onpause = function () {
                isPlaying = false;
              };
            });
            let isPlaying = false;

            function togglePlay() {
              if (isPlaying) {
                myAudio.pause()
              } else {
                myAudio.play();
              }
            }
          </script>
          <audio id="myAudio" src="./styles/music/musica.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>

          <a class="btn" role="button" onClick="togglePlay()">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="35" height="35" fill="currentColor"
              class="bi bi-play-circle-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
              <path
                d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM6.79 5.093A.5.5 0 0 0 6 5.5v5a.5.5 0 0 0 .79.407l3.5-2.5a.5.5 0 0 0 0-.814l-3.5-2.5z" />
            </svg></a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="interfaz" class="my-row ">
    <div class="container fluid padding-interfaz">
        <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path
                        d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 1 10 10a10 10 0 0 1-10 10A10 10 0 0 1 2 12A10 10 0 0 1 12 2m0 2c-4.08 0-7.45 3.05-7.94 7h4.07c.44-1.73 2.01-3 3.87-3c1.86 0 3.43 1.27 3.87 3h4.07c-.49-3.95-3.86-7-7.94-7m0 16c4.08 0 7.45-3.05 7.94-7h-4.07c-.44 1.73-2.01 3-3.87 3c-1.86 0-3.43-1.27-3.87-3H4.06c.49 3.95 3.86 7 7.94 7m0-10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"
                        fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                <label for="numero" class="texto">Introduce el ID:</label>
                <input type="number" id="identificador" name="identificador" placeholder="ID del Pokemon" min="1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" role="img" width="1em" height="1em"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path
                        d="M12 2a10 10 0 0 1 10 10a10 10 0 0 1-10 10A10 10 0 0 1 2 12A10 10 0 0 1 12 2m0 2c-4.08 0-7.45 3.05-7.94 7h4.07c.44-1.73 2.01-3 3.87-3c1.86 0 3.43 1.27 3.87 3h4.07c-.49-3.95-3.86-7-7.94-7m0 16c4.08 0 7.45-3.05 7.94-7h-4.07c-.44 1.73-2.01 3-3.87 3c-1.86 0-3.43-1.27-3.87-3H4.06c.49 3.95 3.86 7 7.94 7m0-10a2 2 0 0 0-2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2 2a2 2 0 0 0 2-2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2z"
                        fill="currentColor" /></svg>
                <label for="nombre" class="texto">Introduce el nombre:</label>
                <input type="text" id="pokemon" name="pokemon" placeholder="Nombre del Pokemon">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                <button id="boton-json">Cargar JSON</button>
                <button id="boton-mostrar">Mostrar seleccionados</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
  
  <div id="interfaz" class="my-row ">
    <div class="container fluid">
      <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <button onClick="window.location.reload();" class="mt-4">Refresh Page</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="zona-pokemon" class="my-row mt-4">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <div id="contenedor" class="tabla">

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa la función de javascript indexOf().
Te funcionará con vanilla, jQuery y lo que sea.

Ejemplo:

```
var name = 'Blastoise';
var search = 'blas';
if (name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) !== -1) {
    //Encontrado
}
```

Fíjate que incorporo toLowerCase() para permitir buscar tanto 'Blas' como 'blas', porque indexOf() es case sensitive.